# Capture Images and show in RecyclerView : Too much work on the main thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-recyclerview, imageview, android-runonuithread

I am trying to capture images in my Android App using camera and show it in a list using `RecyclerView`

But because the images are quite heavy in size (6-7 MB each) and my list is can contains approx 8-9 images, I can see this in my logs:-

```
06-08 17:22:44.318 14283 14283 I Choreographer: Skipped 40 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

And it's not just about the logs. I can even see that when I am trying to capture the image with camera in the foreground, sometimes(frequency : 30%) my application is getting killed and automatically recreated. Because of this, I am losing my images that were earlier captured.

This is my code to capture the image written in my `SampleFragment.kt`:-

```
fun onBtnTakePicture() {
        val cameraIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
        outputFileName = "${System.currentTimeMillis()}.jpg"
        val photo = File(context!!.filesDir, outputFileName)
        val outputFileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context!!, AUTHORITY_APP_FILES,photo)
        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri)
        cameraIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION)
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE)
    }

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if(resultCode == AppCompatActivity.RESULT_OK){
            if(requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE){
                    //To add to db, we need to add this in view model
                    transactionViewModel.addImagePathInList(outputFileName)

                    //to show in the UI, we need to add it into this list
                    myCardsList.add(FeatureCarouselCardData(outputFileName))

                    featureCardsView.notifyAdapaterAboutDataSetChange()
            }
        }
    }

private lateinit var featureCardsView: FeatureCarouselView

override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
..........
..........
featureCardsView = binding.featureCardsView
featureCardsView.showFeatureCarouselCards(myCardsList)
..........
..........
}
```

Adapter object is created in my class extending the RecyclerView :  `FeatureCarouselView.kt`

```
fun showFeatureCarouselCards(featureCarouselCards: List<FeatureCarouselCardData>){
        this.featureCarouselCards = featureCarouselCards

        featureCarouselAdapter = FeatureCarouselAdapter(context, featureCarouselCards)
        adapter = featureCarouselAdapter

    }
```

This is the `onBindViewHolder` function in my `FeatureCarouselAdapter.kt` class

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: FeatureCarouselViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentItem = featureCarouselCards[position]
        var bitmap = mContext.resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_file_not_found).toBitmap()
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "currentItem in onBindViewHolder : "+currentItem)
        try {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "try")
            val photo = File(mContext.filesDir, currentItem.fileName)
            val outputFileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(mContext, AUTHORITY_APP_FILES,photo)
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(mContext.contentResolver, outputFileUri)
        }catch (e: FileNotFoundException) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "catch filenotfound")
            e.printStackTrace()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "catch ioexception")
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
    }
```

While I know that there are some tools that can be used to load images alternatively and efficiently like Picasso or Glide. But these needs INTERNET permissions to be added in the Manifest file.

I want to keep my app offline only. So want to avoid this.

How can I achieve this?

###### Update

I even tried using loading images using Glide:-

```
Glide.with(mContext)
                .load(outputFileUri)
                .into(holder.imageView)
```

But still, I am facing the same problem. So, what could be the possible root cause for my issue?

Comment: You can use `remove` node in `AndroidManifest` to not add Internet permission in the final apk. With these libraries, you can easily use a low quality images (thumbnails) and still keep the recyclerview performance.

Comment: @Darshan thanks for your response. But I tried using Glide as well. It didn't help and my problem is same.

Comment: Can you try using `.override(size)`? Play around with the size values to handle image quality.

Comment: @Darshan I have tried this as well. This is also not working.

I can see that when Camera Activity is launched for result, in the background my app's activity is getting killed. So, I don't think that it's an image inflation issue.

Comment: `Because of this, I am losing my images that were earlier captured.` Not possible. Those are image files. And those files will not be deleted if your activity finishes. Its quite normal that your activity gets killed if it is not the top one. That you learned at lesson one Android programming. Your code should expect that. Further you will not get that message if you handle your images not in the main thread.

Comment: @blackapps by losing images, I mean the references that I created within my code (say a list of file paths). Those are getting lost because application is getting recreated.

But, I will have to do this on the main thread only right?
```holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)```

Comment: You shouldn't use heavy methods in your `onBindViewHolder()`. Use a background thread to load and resize images.
BTW, you should also move this line from the `onBindViewHolder()` method:
`var bitmap = mContext.resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_file_not_found).toBitmap()`

Comment: @AlexanderSuslov Thanks for your response. I have done the changes. But the crash thing is something related to the Camera application as it's happening with all the apps like Whatsapp, Facebook, Instagram when I am trying to capture an image from within these apps.

Comment: @RohitSingla The main cause of the crash is that you are trying to hold quite heavy images in the RecyclerView. If you don't use the Camera app but use a file picker to load such images, the issue will persist. You should resize all images that you show in the RecyclerView in order to significantly reduce their size.